# Why don't we need to install Node.js as we do JRE to run Java Applets?

Tags: javascript, java, runtime

I remember I have [installed JRE on the machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2971611/3552975) many times to run Java Applets, but when I run Javascript enabled chrome extensions I don't need to install Node.js.

I'm learning Javascript and get to know that Node.js is the runtime environment of Javascript just as JRE for Java, then I wonder why we need to install JRE to run Applets but don't Node.js to run web extensions?

Comment: Node.js is one engine. Chrome contains another engine. You don't need Node.js to run JavaScript in a browser.

Comment: Java Applets? They're dead. No browser supports them at all anymore. node.js uses [v8](https://v8.dev/). The same JavaScript engine from Google Chrome.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can Applets survive by using the same runtime engine v8?

Comment: v8 is a JavaScript engine. JavaScript is unrelated to Java. So, **no**. Applets can't survive using the same runtime engine v8. Applets are already dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node.js` is an environment as you noted, but it's not *the* environment. Browsers each have their own. Check this out for [more](https://olinations.medium.com/the-javascript-runtime-environment-d58fa2e60dd0). As an aside, `Node.js` is actually built atop the [Chrome V8 Engine](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/serverless/glossary/what-is-chrome-v8/#:%7E:text=js%20is%20a%20runtime%20environment,not%20have%20built%2Din%20sandboxing.).